# Loading image from Firebase is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Swift development, and am wondering why it is taking so long for the image to show. It's a 4.44kb image whose URL is stored in a Firestore document. It takes a second before it shows, which isn't very good for the UX. As I said, the image (a barcode) is just 4.44kb, which makes me wonder why loading for example an image from Instagram or Facebook is faster than loading this image.

My code:

In my viewDidLoad:

```
dbRef.getDocument { (document, err) in
        if let e = err {
            print("Error retrieving document: \(e)")
        } else {
            let data = document?.data()
            
            if let imageURL = data?[K.User.barcodeImage] as? String {
                // let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: imageURL)
                let url = NSURL(string: imageURL)
                self.downloadImage(from: url as! URL)
                let number = data![K.User.barcodeNumber] as! String
                self.cardNumber.text = number
                UserDefaults.standard.set(number, forKey: K.User.barcodeNumber)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

The rest:

```
func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
}

func downloadImage(from url: URL) {
    getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
            self?.cardCode.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Does this have to do with DispatchQueue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: From this code, it isn't obvious where you're downloading the image from and it doesn't appear to be Firebase Storage. Where is the image being downloaded from?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. The image is stored in Firebase storage, and the link to that image is stored in Firestore. @bsod

Comment: You mentioned the url of the image being on firestore, where is the image actually hosted? If you access the image directly by its url (without fetching it from firestore) how long does it take to load? Trying to see if the latency is in firestore side or wherever the image is hosted

Comment: Why aren't you using the Firebase Storage API to fetch this image? You're jumping through unnecessary hoops here using `URLSession`.

Comment: @AndresS the image is stored in Firebase storage. When I directly inserted the url it takes around a second as well...

Comment: @bsod, wow, thank you for mentioning. I tried it, and that makes it so easy, thank you! Unfortunately, the speed issue wasn't resolved by that. I used this code `storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cardCode.image = image
            }
        }` [But this is still the result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r70tpuqa7uxhre2/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-17%20at%2018.47.08.mov?dl=0)

Comment: One second is not an unreasonable amount of time to fetch data from a database and then a file from storage. Why is an app like Instagram faster? Mostly due to very aggressive caching and preloading, which are things you can build and incorporate into your app as well. There is also the issue of the speed of the actual network you're on right now which may be the biggest factor. All that said, if you're using the APIs correctly, and coding everything else correctly, then the speed of Firebase definitely should not be an issue in the slightest--it's incredibly fast from my experience.

Comment: @bsod, thank you. I'll look into loading the image from cache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 second latency is not unreasonable but you can try enabling cache headers from [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.SettableMetadata#optional-cachecontrol) / [GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) to improve performance.

Comment: I would also look into NSCache. I used this for things like profile images in collection views where the content is reloaded quite frequently.